# How to get coordinate of text from line paragraph pdf itext5

Tags: java, pdf, text, itext, coordinates

How to get coordinate of left of line text paragraph pdf. I mean like pic (x,y).
Coordinate per line.
I use itext5 and java

[image]

Comment: Use text extraction with a custom text extraction strategy which stores the lowest x coordinate of each line (text at approximately the same y coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with itext, but if you use pdfbox, you can override the `writePage` method of the `PDFTextStripper` class. The position of all text is in the member variable "charactersByArticle" of `PDFTextStripper` class, so you can then get the leftmost coordinate from this variable and use it to minus font size is your need.I guess there are similar classes in itext.